# How to write a recursive function for palindromic primes?

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

I have been trying to write a Python program which uses a recursive function to find the palindromic primes between two integers supplied as input. Example of palindromic prime: 313

I already know how to write a recursive function for palindromes, but I am struggling with this one a lot. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: ignore the entire prime business - just figure out how to do the palindrom business.

Comment: But I have to also check whether the numbers are prime numbers, right?

Comment: @John yes, but you have two criteria, work on one at a time.

Comment: yep. but that's the "easy" part. `foreach(prime numbers in range) { check if palindrome }`

Comment: ^ that non python code :P.  // Anyways, you should use your palindrome function and insert an `isprime` check after you get your palindrome. If this is really inefficient (i.e. << 1% of the time), you could look at finding all primes (same function) and then using mpolendiks answer to check for palindrome

Comment: How large can the two integers defining the range be?

Comment: @Stefan the limit is 30000

Comment: @MarcB well, I really don't know how I could modify my palindrome function to check for prime numhers

Comment: @Matthew Is there a way to do this without using modules?

Comment: you're not understanding. there's NO point in combining the two functions. you have one function that generates/finds prime numbers, then you can feed those primes to your palindrome function.

Comment: @John Good, that allows cheating (as I do :-)

Comment: @MarcB Palindromes a lot rarer than primes in the specified range, though, so it could make sense to do it the other way around - generate palindromes and check primality.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: either way... doesn't really matter in practical terms.

Comment: John: It would probably help if you showed us your palindrome function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> recursive function for palindromes

Presumably to do the palindrome check recursively you check the outer characters:

```
def is_pali(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and is_pali(s[1:-1])
```

---

Now you can iterate over the numbers and see which are palindromes:

```
[i for i in range(n, m) if is_pali(str(i))]
```

Comment: In `is_pali`, shouldn't the last return statement be `return s[0] == s[-1] and is_pali(s[1:-1])`?

Comment: @wflynny yes, definitely -whoops!

Comment: @Andy  I already have the palindrome function. My problem is to modify it so that it checks for prime numbers which are palindromes.

Comment: @John That'll be the str in is_pali(str(i)) part... :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already went through this idea but here's what I would do...

If you have a palindrome function like this one:

```
def palindrome(word):
if len(word) == 1 or (len(word) == 2 and word[0] == word[1]):
    return True
else:
    if word[0] == word[len(word)-1]:
        return palindrome(word[1] + word[len(word)-2])
    else:
        return False
```

And let's say you have a function to figure out if a number is prime (this I take from [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)):

```
def is_prime(number):
if number > 1:
    if number == 2:
        return True
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for current in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number) + 1), 2):
        if number % current == 0: 
            return False
    return True
return False
```

You can just call the validation when you find out if your number is a palindrome (casting it to str first).
The missing part is generate the combination of the two integers you might get but well, that's a simple one.

Hope this helps.

-Edit:
Adding a recursive function for getting primes:

```
def prime(number,limit = 1):
if limit == number:
    return True
else:
    if number % limit == 0 and limit != 1:
        return False
    else:
        return prime(number, limit + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a similar code for palindromes. However, the second one for checking prime numbers isn't recursive. I only need to use recursive functions

Comment: I updated with a recursive function for figuring out primes. It's not that efficient because evaluates from 1 until the number you give if it's divisible but it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since 30000 is the limit, this works (101101 is the smallest number it gets wrong):

```
>>> [n for n in range(2, 500) if str(n) == str(n)[::-1] and (2**n-1)%n == 1]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383]
```

You can of course also use the `(2**n-1)%n == 1` primality test in your own recursive palindrome function that you already have.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test

Answer (score -1):

Instead of recursive solution, what about using more effective list slicing?

```
def isPalindrome(number):
    nstr = str(number)
    return nstr == nstr[::-1]
```

This works by converting the number to string and comparing it's reversed counterpart. There is also known algorithm for determining the palindrome,
using global variable:

```
sum = 0


def is_palindrome(number):
    return palindrome_sum(number) == number


def palindrome_sum(number):
    global sum
    if number != 0:
        remainder = number % 10
        sum = sum * 10 + remainder
        palindrome_sum(number / 10) * 10 + remainder

    return sum
```

For mathematical recursive function without global variable, this algorithm can be used:

```
import math

def is_palindrome(number):
    return palindrome_sum(number) == number


def palindrome_sum(number, sum=0):
    iters = 0
    if number != 0:
        iters = int(math.log10(number))
        remainder = number % 10
        sum = palindrome_sum(number / 10) + remainder * 10 ** iters

    return sum
```

It uses the length of number to find it's position in the resulting number. The length can be computed by `int(math.log10(number))`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am supposed to use a recursive function only

Answer (score -1):

This solution uses the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find the prime numbers less than n. It then uses a basic palindrome check which of those prime numbers are palindromes. The check avoids converting the `int`s to `str`s, which is a time consuming operation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

def primeslt(n):
    """Finds all primes less than n"""

    if n < 3:
        return []

    A = [True] * n
    A[0], A[1] = False, False

    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if A[i]:
            j = i**2
            while j < n:
                A[j] = False
                j += i

    return (num for num in xrange(n) if A[num])

def is_palindrome(n):
    digits = []
    while n > 0:
        digits.append(n%10)
        n /= 10
    return digits == digits[::-1]

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            i = int(raw_input("Palindromic primes less than... "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Input must be an integer."

    print filter(is_palindrome, primeslt(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you have any questions about how this code works, feel free to ask me by commenting on my answer. Best of luck!